# how to send mail automatically everyday when workflow completed successfully and also send an email when it run long

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, informatica-powerexchange, informatica-data-integration-hub

I want to receive an email when
1)The workflow will be successfully completed in time and a completion Notification will be sent to the respective person(e-mail id) or support group(distribution list) via the email task or the post-session e-mail notification in the session task.

2. The workflow will be continuing to run in excess of the expected time due to some issues (like network, data, etc).In such cases the “STILL RUNNING” notification will be sent to the respective person (e-mail id) or support group(distribution list) via the email task or the post-session e-mail notification in the session task.

Comment: What language??

Comment: This is not a language, this is a ETL tool.

Answer (score 0):

For the **scenario 1** just follow the guide linked by @rownum-highart.

For the **scenario 2** use a parallel flow with a timer. Combine the two flows with `Decision Task`. Remember to use `Treat the input links as` set to `OR`. followed by `Email Task` with a condition of your session status.

[image: workflow overview]

[image: decision task properties]

Comment: thank u so much! but wt if i have multiple sessions and i want to recive an email when all session should be run within time and if not completed within time i also should recive an email

Comment: Either apply the above in parallel to your sessions sequence, or for each session separately. Give it a try and let us know if you'd face issues. Good luck!